# Error during fitting of data on model. Target output needs to match

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

When trying to do:

```
model_training.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=100)
```

I get this error:

A target array with shape (25000, 2) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3, 2) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Here is my model setup.
any ideas appreciated!

```
model_training = Sequential()
# input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(300,1))
model_training.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(300,1)))
model_training.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh'))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh'))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh'))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh'))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model_training.add(LSTM(300, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(Dense(2))
model_training.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model_training.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model_training.summary())
```

X_train shape: (25000, 300)
Y_train shape: (25000, 2)

Comment: Needed to flatten the 3d data to 2d to match the output.
```model_training.add(Flatten()) ```
Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
model_training.add(Flatten())
```

This fixed it for me.
Needed to flatten the data to match the output.